# Spark Streaming only streams files created after the stream initialization time

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

Is there any way to configure the `textFileStream` source such that it will process any file added to the source directory regardless of the file create time?

To demonstrate the issue, I created a basic Spark Streaming application that uses `textFileStream` as a source and prints the stream contents to the console. When an existing file created prior to running the application is copied into the source directory, nothing is printed to the console. When a file created after the application starts running is copied to the source directory, the file contents are printed. Below is my code for reference.

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Streaming Test")
                          .setMaster("local[*]")

val spark = new SparkContext(conf)
val ssc = new StreamingContext(spark, Seconds(5))

val fileStream = ssc.textFileStream("/stream-source")

val streamContents = fileStream.flatMap(_.split(" "))

streamContents.print()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the documented behavior of the [FileInputDStream](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/streaming/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/dstream/FileInputDStream.scala#L38).

If we would like to consume existing files in that directory, we can use the Spark API to load these files and apply our desired logic to them.

```
val existingFiles = sparkContext.textFile(path)
```

or

```
val existingFilesDS = sparkSession.read.text(path)
```

And then after, setup and start the streaming logic.
We could even use the data of the already existing files in the processing of the new ones.

Comment: The documentation in the source code is slightly ambiguous -  `In this case "new" means files that became visible to readers during that time period`. This makes it seem as though the file does not need to be created after the time period begins, but only made available to the source after the time period begins.